# mvc Unit Test Provider did not return ProviderManifestToken String

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, connection-string

currently using NUnit to test and I'm getting a 
**"Provider did not return ProviderManifestToken String"**
error whenever i execute the test. I figured it's not able to access the web.config which is situated in separate project. I was wondering how to go about passing the connection string to the Unit Test project? Or do i have to store a connection string in the Unit test project itself? resx file? no?
any help is appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have your unit-test assembly named School.Student.Tests.dll, then you need to make sure that School.Student.Tests.dll.config is there with the proper connection string.
Or you need to copy your connection string from web.config to app.config in your unit test project